# Converting np.int16 to torch.ShortTensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, pytorch-dataloader

I have many NumPy arrays of dtype `np.int16` that I need to convert to `torch.Tensor` within a `torch.utils.data.Dataset`.  This `np.int16` ideally gets converted to a `torch.ShortTensor` of size `torch.int16` ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch-dtype)).

`torch.from_numpy(array)` will convert the data to `torch.float64`, which takes up 4X more memory than `torch.int16` (64 bits vs 16 bits).  I have a LOT of data, so I care about this.

How can I convert a numpy array to a `torch.Tensor` minimizing memory?

Comment: Opening a Python interpreter and typing `t = torch.from_numpy(numpy.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=numpy.int16))` will indeed convert `numpy.int16` to `torch.int16`. Are you sure all your data is int16? Maybe you could also try [as_tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_tensor.html) which explicitly accepts the dtype (although in case of Numpy arrays it says it just delegates to `from_numpy` AFAIU).

Comment: [`from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html) sadly has no `dtype` kwarg, and I didn't know about [`as_tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_tensor.html), which seems to share memory (good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a numpy array to torch tensor:

```
array = np.ones((1000, 1000), dtype=np.int16)
print("NP Array size: {}".format(array.nbytes))
t = torch.as_tensor(array) # as_tensor avoids copying of array 
print("Torch tensor type: {}".format(t.dtype))
print("Torch tensor size: {}".format(t.storage().nbytes()))

NP Array size: 2000000
Torch tensor type: torch.int16
Torch tensor size: 2000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Would you mind also adding [`torch.as_tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_tensor.html)?  It reuses the same memory (avoids copy), so it's even less memory than `torch.tensor`